# Committing a value to SharedPreferences from a spinner when a button is pressed

Tags: android, spinner, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to have a user select an item from a spinner, and when the 'submit' button is pressed, have the data committed to SharedPrefences.

Here's where the spinner is located:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dob_month);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.months_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And here is what is in the method when the submit button is pressed:

```
String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    editor.putString("dob_month",dobMonth).commit();
```

1) It's saying 'spinner' is undefined in the method for when the button is pressed

2) I know I'm missing a listener for the spinner, how and where would I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've initialized spinner in `onCreate()` so nobody from outside that method can access it.

Change it to this

```
    Spinner mSpinner;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);

    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dob_month);
    ...
```

Comment: This is more of a general Java question - if I initialize it like that and the variable changes inside a method, does that change happen globally?

Comment: @tuzion yes if you declare it globally, whatever changes you make in other methods apply globally too.

Comment: Also, just tried it, it worked! THANK YOU! I've been beating my head on the table for so long over such a simple thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared and initialized the sharedpreference and editor objects?.

Comment: Yep. Those aren't the problem; I have several other values being properly written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything you need to make a spinner work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youractivity);
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerxmlname);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add()= //set all month names
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items );
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            }


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    // TO code what should be done when an item is selected,in your case commit
            //to sharedpreferences
    String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            editor.putString("dob_month",
                                        (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).commit();

    }
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Also note that your Activity should implement the interface OnItemSelectedListener